# WinRT C# Play a viddler video using MediaElement

Tags: c#, webview, winrt-xaml, mediaelement

I am trying to play a Viddler video in my application but i cant get it to work.
Here is my simple code:

XAML:

```
  < MediaElement VerticalAlignment="Center" Visibility="Visible" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
    Name="myMediaElement" Height="350" 
    Width="640" />
```

And my c#:

```
myMediaElement = new MediaElement();
Uri url = new Uri("http://www.viddler.com/embed/5b17d44f/");
myMediaElement.Source = url;
myMediaElement.Play();
```

Any help would be great!  When i arrive on the page, nothing happens, the application does not break it just does nothing....

Edit:
In the end I have just decided to call the http://www.viddler.com/embed/5b17d44f/ url into a Webview, its not the best idea but it works.

Comment: What exactly happens when you run your code? Furthermore are you 100% postive that `MediaElement` even contained within the WinRT .NET Profile.  Based on my research `MediaElement` cannot be used within an application being targeted against the `WinRT .NET Profile` you will have to develop your own solution.

Comment: When I run my code nothing happens, it would seem that I am missing something, on the SDK tutorial of MS they show examples of using the MediaElement but they use it with a FileOpenPicker module.

Answer (score 0):

1. Dont create a new MediaElemet. You already have one created (XAML).
2. Set `AutoPlay="True"` in your XAML

**Edit**: Play works only if the media is already loaded.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it doesn't seem to fix my problem, I think that i need to download the video on the device and then play it, because playing it directly from an url does not seem possible.