# How to put a Binding on a video

Tags: winrt-xaml, bitmapimage, xaml-binding

I've stored a video to a BitmapImage and want the user to be able to replay it. However, when I run my program it treats my BitmapImage like it's empty when it's not. I've tried doing the same thing with a picture saved to a BitmapImage and any picture will appear and fill the screen like I tell it to, but videos just don't show up. Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant store a video in a bitmapimage. Videos should be stored in StorageFile.

Comment: Okay, so how would I get my video out of a StorageFile?

Comment: Or rather how can I put a Binding on a StorageFile. I can get the StorageFile without any problems but I don't know how to use it with a Binding.

Comment: Use mediaelement, set the source of the control using the setsource method and play the media element using play method. refer this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13181809/winrt-c-sharp-play-a-viddler-video-using-mediaelement

Comment: you can try this: http://weblogs.asp.net/jdanforth/binding-mediaelement-to-a-viewmodel-in-a-windows-8-store-app but its not recommended to have binding for mediaelement's source property.

Comment: SetSource was in fact the thing I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use in your dictionary:

`<MediaElement x:Key="Video1" Source="ms-appx:///Assets/Videos/Video.mp4"/`

and then on page:

`<MediaElement Source="{StaticResource Video1}"/>`

remember to start width AutoPlay="True".